# Как нарисовать дугу? (SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

У меня вот вопрос, как нарисовать дугу? Именно как нарисовать дугу между двумя точками и через радиус искривления, точку искривления? 
(Через масив точек - это я знаю, а вот как эти точки найти?)

Comment: используйте sf::VertexArray
https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1VertexArray.php

Comment: Я понял, но как эти точки найти? Каждую точку, в дуге этой

Comment: Возьмите растеризатор, например Direct2D, там можно векторную графику преобразовать в геометрию для отрисовки