# Окружность sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Как нарисовать 1/4 окружности в SFML?

Comment: Вот недавно был аналогичный вопрос - [Как нарисовать дугу? (SFML)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056510/Как-нарисовать-дугу-sfml)

Comment: @user7860670 Я когда то где то видел способ через LinesStrip?, но второй день не могу найти ее. А способ из того вопроса не самый оптимальный.

Comment: возьмите исходный текст CircleShape.cpp, он всего 85 строк и сделайте из него класс дуги

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу, в SFML нет графических примитивов для рисования кривых, кроме Circle.

В таком случае есть по меньшей мере два выхода

- сгенерировать набор точек дуги, например, с помощью алгоритма Брезенхема, или через Sin/Cos и построить по ним ломаную
- если это возможно - установить прямоугольный регион отсечения нужного размера (от центра окружности) и нарисовать Circle. Вероятно, для этого можно использовать View